# Checking for the same items inside a list in Python

Tags: python, list, random

I was making a Set exercise generator for my math teacher, however I stumbled onto a problem. I was using randint to generate all the numbers inside the "sets" (which are lists), and many time I ended up with the same integers repeated 2 to 4 times, and that is impossible in a conventional algebraic set. Is there a way for me to take of the repeated items without affecting the entire list?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
while max != min:
    if max < min:
        raise ArithmeticError
    set1.append(randint(0, 100))
    set2.append(randint(0, 100))
    max -= 1
```

PS: The min/max part is not important, it's just to specify how many random numbers are added to the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a [built-in set type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). Just wrap your set1 lists with `set()`.

I've created an example here: https://repl.it/CEnz

UPDATE:

```
x = [2,3,4,2,3,6,7,89]
y = set(x)
z = list(y)
print x, type(x)
print y, type(y)
print z, type(z)
```

will print

```
[2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 6, 7, 89] <type 'list'>
set([2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 89]) <type 'set'>
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 89] <type 'list'>
```

respectively for x,y and z.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer and for the example! Now my code is working perfectly!

Comment: that's a pleasure :)

Comment: Please post your code **in your answer**. If the external link rots, this answer will be absolutely useless. Only use links for reference.

Comment: I'll consider this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `set` instead of a list

```
s1 = set()
s2 = set()
# loop logic
s1.add(random.randint(0, 100))
s2.add(random.randint(0, 100))
```

There is a caveat here.The length of the sets will not be be deterministic as duplicate random ints are discarded. So you might probably have to modify the loop logic slightly if you want equal number of elements in both.